# Page doesn't display properly with UTF-8 charset (PHP)

Tags: php, file, encoding, utf-8

Texts are set UFT-8 at Database,
Meta Charset is set to UTF-8 and File Encoding is UTF-8..

But page still doesn't display properly.. Please help..

Comment: _“Please help..”_ – please ast [proper question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through my web application (Apache, MySQL, PHP, ...)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through-my-web-application-apache-mysql-php)

Comment: Your HTTP server (Apache ?) returns Response encoded in UTF-8 ? have you a response header which looks like `Content-Type : text/html; charset=UTF-8` ?

Answer (score 2):

In notepad++ choose utf-8 without bom as saving type, don't forget if you use a mysql you must write utf8 not utf-8 remove (-), and don't forget to set your SQL as in example if you use MySQL use `mysqli_set_charset($link,'utf8');` or in fiest query line

```
set names utf8
```